# Spring+hibernate+jpa how does it work?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

In the new project that I have joined, they keep using the terms Hibernate and JPA interchangeably. So, I tried to dive down into the code and try to understand how this whole thing works (I am new to Spring, JPA and Hibernate world). I'll try to put the code here for better understanding:
1) There is a @Configuration class where they have the following:

```
@Resource
private HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateOracleJpaVendorAdapter;

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = 
new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateOracleJpaVendorAdapter);
entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("abc");
             .
             .
```

So, in this configuration class, we are returning an EntityManagerFactory.

2) Then there is a persistor class marked @Persistor, where a method of repository is invoked (for example, for a save operation):

```
  blahblahRepository.save(blahblahEntity, abcdef);
```

3) Finally there is a repository class which is annotated @Repository. Then again, they have this piece of code:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "same as the name in persistence.xml")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

The "save" method wraps around the persist method of JPA:

```
getEntityManager().persist(entityObject);
```

My questions are as follows:
1) There is no word about Hibernate other than in the hibernateJpaVendorAdapter. I searched the entire workspace and it showed just 3 occurences of the word hibernate, all in the configuration file.
2) From whatever knowledge I have, one should use either an EntityManagerFactory or an EntityManager but we are doing both?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is one of the implementations of the JPA spec. Since your project chose Hibernate as its JPA implementation, it uses the JPA API, which delegates the Hibernate. Just like when you use the JDBC API, which delegates to a specific Oracle or PostgreSQL driver.

EntityManagerFactory, as its name indicates, is a factory for EntityManager. I don't see why you wouldn't use both. EntityManager is the main interface of the JPA API, used to execute all database operations (find, persist, merge, query, etc.). EntityManagerFactory must be configured before asking it to create an EntityManager.

Comment: You're not doing it. Spring does it for you, and injects it into your Spring beans.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but we are not creating entity manager from EntityManagerFactory. Whatever blogs/documentation I've read so far, it says either: @PersistenceContext(unit="abc") EntityManager em; OR @PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory emf; EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() creates EntityManager. Is my understanding wrong? If not then why are we doing it this way?